# Neighborhood computation for atom lattice

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Dear Mathematica users,

Given a 2D atom lattice (that is, a set of points within the plane), I need to compute the first three neighbors for each atom/point (the closest 3 points to each atom, taken into account that an atom cannot have more than three neighbors).

I managed to build a brute force code which actually works well but it's highly slow when approaching a high number of atoms.

Is there any way to solve this problem in Mathematica? any built-in function? any other approach apart from the brute-force one?

I did some research over the internet but I couldn't find anything fitting the goal written above.

Thanks a lot,

Carlos

Answer (score 3):

Can you use `Nearest` and `NearestFunction` ?
See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/CreateAVoronoiDiagram.html